# How can I exclude empties arrays from an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, mapping

I've succeeded to retrieve the array which contains the product (filter by an ID) but I got empties arrays in the output too.

Here the piece of code I wrote for the example:

```js
var category = [{
    "reference": 'BC-ENFANT',
    "name": 'Pour les Enfants',
    "description": 'Soins pour les enfants...',
    "id": 155,
    "productList": [{
        "id": 13655,
        "reference": 'PROD_ENFANT_01',
        "name": 'Brushing'
      },
      {
        "id": 13656,
        "reference": 'PROD_ENFANT_03',
        "name": 'Soins'
      },
    ]
  },

  {
    "reference": 'BC-FEMME',
    "name": 'Pour les Femmes',
    "description": 'Prestations pour les femmes',
    "id": 154,
    "productList": [{
        "id": 13657,
        "reference": 'PROD_ENFANT_01',
        "name": 'Brushing'
      },
      {
        "id": 13658,
        "reference": 'PROD_ENFANT_03',
        "name": 'Soins'
      },
    ]
  }
];

var productList = category.map(p => {
  return p.productList
});
var product = productList.map(p => p.filter(p => p.id === 13657).map(pp => {
  return {
    Reference: pp.reference,
    Name: pp.name,
    Quantity: 1
  }
}));
console.log(product)
```

Comment: user filter with `arr.length > 0` or simple `arr.length`.

Comment: Is your goal to create a single array containing the objects from all the `productList` arrays? What output are you expecting? I ask as I believe the logic can be simplified, and the issue of empty arrays can be avoided by amending the generation logic without the need for `filter()`

Comment: it looks like your 
```var product = productList.map```   should be filtering first before map  ```var product = productList.filer( p => check you have data).map(p ....)```  because the map function will return an entry for all items

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My goal is to retrieve the product object from all the productList

Comment: @developer okay, I'm going to trying to check the data first and them mapping as you suggested to me

Comment: @harili thanks for clarifying, I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to retrieve the product object from all the productList

In this case you can use `map()` to create a multi-dimensional array of them and then `flat()` to combine it in to a single dimension array, like this:

```js
var category = [{"reference":'BC-ENFANT',"name":'Pour les Enfants',"description":'Soins pour les enfants...',"id":155,"productList":[{"id":13655,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},{"id":13656,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'},]},{"reference":'BC-FEMME',"name":'Pour les Femmes',"description":'Prestations pour les femmes',"id":154,"productList":[{"id":13657,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_01',"name":'Brushing'},{"id":13658,"reference":'PROD_ENFANT_03',"name":'Soins'}]}];

var productList = category.map(p => p.productList).flat();
console.log(productList)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me twice times ! ahah.

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)